# Help needed editing music more precisely in Premiere

Tags: premiere, audio

I have shot a video with 23,976 FPS and now need to expand the timeline to double that, so I can make more precise edits with the music.

But Premiere Pro only allows certain FPS

[image]

Is there a way to set custom FPS? As there isn't even a 48p Option like Hobbit used.

Or are there other better ways to edit music more precisly within Pr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the quickest option for better accuracy of audio editing would be to right-click on the actual numbers of the timeline and select "Show Audio Time Units" ?